# "String or binary data would be truncated" on DBCC CHECKIDENT

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, identity, dbcc

I am getting a "String or binary data would be truncated" error when i try to reset the Identity.

```
Declare @tableNameWithSchema varchar(max)
SET  @tableNameWithSchema = '[' + @table_schema + '].[' + @tablenamee + ']'
DBCC CHECKIDENT (@tableNameWithSchema, RESEED, 0)
```

Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Are you sure that this error is occurring at this point? Because you're clearly not showing the entire query.

Comment: `QUOTENAME` is a built-in function for escaping identifiers that's more convenient and more reliable than adding delimiters yourself.

Comment: @ZLK yeah it was not a complete query but i was sure it was from this line. I was querying the DB for all tables and resetting the Identities in a loop. I have posted the answer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the information. How do i use it in this case? I am using variables to set another variable.

Comment: `SET @tableNameWithSchema = QUOTENAME(@table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tablenamee)`. This has the benefit of working correctly even if some malefactor puts a `]` in the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By trial and error method I found out the issue: `DBCC CHECKIDENT` does not take a `varchar(max)`. It should be `varchar(100)`. Although I do not understand why `MAX` is wrong. If anyone knows why please let us know.

Following code worked:

```
declare @tableNameWithSchema varchar(100)
SET  @tableNameWithSchema = '[' + @table_schema + '].[' + @tablenamee + ']'
DBCC CHECKIDENT (@tableNameWithSchema, RESEED, 0)
```

I am keeping this post so that it might be useful for someone else.

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using? I just checked on my platform with SS2012 Express and using `VARCHAR(MAX)` worked without errors.

Comment: @TT. It is SQL Server 2012. Do you mean you used     MAX and it worked ?

Comment: Yes, I took both your `DBCC` command (`NORESEED` and `RESEED`), ran them with a variable of type `VARCHAR(MAX)` and I got no error messages.

Comment: Sorry it was just `RESEED`. I just edited my answer. Although I don't understand how `MAX` worked for `RESEED` in your case. There is no difference

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @tableNameWithSchema varchar(max),@table_schema VARCHAR(100) = 'dbo',@tablename VARCHAR(100) = 'Your_TableName' 
SET  @tableNameWithSchema = '[' + @table_schema + '].[' + @tablename + ']'
DBCC CHECKIDENT (@tableNameWithSchema, RESEED,0)
```

Comment: “String or binary data would be truncated”

Comment: what you passing in this three parameter

Comment: Table name and schema as a varchar. and maximum characters was 61.

Comment: Increase maximum characters length as 200 then check